# Javascript Avoid Overwriting Listener

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, scroll, listeners

I'm developing a piece of javascript which will run inside a non-friendly iframe.
Fortunally I have an interface which permits me to run javascript inside the iframe parent page but this is not the problem.

The problem is: in my code I need to attach a function to the window.onscroll event of the iframe parent page. Unfortunately I don't know from the beginning on which websites my code will run so I don't know if they already have a function attached to window.onscroll

What will happen if I do a window.onscroll = function(){...} while the website already have one?
Will it be overwritten?
If yes: is there a way to avoid this?

I hope I've explained myself.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It depends on how events are bound. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var oldHandler = null;

if('function' == typeof window.onscroll) {
  oldHandler = window.onscroll; 
}

window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  // your stuff...
  if(oldHandler) oldHandler.call(window, ev);
}
```

Comment: Also note that using jQuery, handlers are automatically "merged". So `$(window).scroll(function() {});` will preserve the original handler.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using jQuery ;)

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait!
But your answer is good for me =D
Thank you!